# Use mic from macbook air when iphone headphones are plugged in

Tags: headphones, macbook-air, microphone

My mic is broken in my iphone headphones, so when i'm on my macbook air i have to pull out the headphones so that the macbook mic is selected.

Is there anyway i can have the headphones plugged in and use the mic from the macbook? I checked in the sound settings and there's only ever one input mic to select from.

Comment: Couldn't you just use another pair of headphones? Alternatively, you might be able to use a TRRS to TRS converter which basically gets rid of the microphone channel.

Comment: @slhck I don't have another pair of headphones otherwise would. I'm not too sure what you mean by TRRS/TRS is there some software you can recommend? Thanks.

Comment: The iPhone headset uses [TRRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRRS) (Tip, Ring, Ring, Sleeve) jacks with a separate ring for the microphone channel. Normal headphones don't have that, and you'd need an adapter to get this working. A female TRS to male TRS adapter would work, or a TRS extension cable. This way, the Mac won't recognize the microphone.